# Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.in C#

Tags: c#

```
private void MINOR_VICTIM_INFO_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable DE = vc.GetMaxMinorNo();
    if (DE.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (DE.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
        {
            txtuniqueminorno.Text = "12345678901";
        }
        else
        {
            int majoradded = Convert.ToInt32(DE.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1;
            txtuniqueminorno.Text = majoradded.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? Did you consider just Googling it to make an effort to understand what it is, why it's happening, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: 12,345,678,901 > 2,147,483,647 I'm guessing somewhere `DE.Rows[0][0]` gets the 12345678901 value...

Comment: it shows an error "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32".

Answer (score -1):

[Integer Limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx)

At some point in your code you have an integer that is outside of these limits. Use break points and the debugger to find when you are using a value that is outside of these limits.

I would guess that if the error is definitely in this section of code, that looking at

```
DE.Rows[0][0]
```

will be where the error lies.

Comment: I believe this is the answer to the vague question. The error IS caused by an integer being outside the limits of the integer